# Find random non-almost-degenerated multivariate polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, approximation, random, multivariate-polynomial

If I randomly draw parameters for a polynomial of degree $n$, say $P_n$, there seems to be big chances that this polynomial can be closely approximated by a polynomial of smaller degree $P_{n-k}, k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

For instance, this $P_5$ (in blue) is easily approximated by a $P_3$ (in red), as measured by their Mean Squared Error on the interval $[-1, 1]$:

[image: P5 easily approximated by P3]

I am interested in random polynomials $P_n$ that are "complete" in the sense that they are **not** easily approximated by lower-degree polynomials.

For instance, this $P_4$ (in orange) fails to approximate the $P_5$ (in blue) as its measured MSE is high.

[image: P4 fails to approximate P5]

How do I randomly draw from this class of polynomials only?

---

Attempt to formalize the problem, and generalize to multivariate polynomials in $d$ dimensions:

Let $t \in \mathbb{R}^{+*}$ be a minimal dissimilarity threshold.
A multivariate polynomial of degree $n$ is considered on the hypercube
$P_n: [-1,1]^d \to \mathbb{R}$.
Its coefficients $a$ can be refered to by $d$ indexes so that $P_n(x)$ can be expressed as the sum of each monom

$P_n(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i_1,\dots,i_d \in \{0,\dots,n\}}{a_{i_1,\dots,i_d} \times x{_1}^{i_1} \times \dots \times x{_d}^{i_d}}$

Each coefficient is restricted to the bounded hypercube $a_{i_1,\dots,i_d} \in [-A,A], A \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

The dissimilarity between two polynomials is defined as (or monotonic with)
$d(P, Q) \propto \displaystyle\int_{x\in[-1,1]^d}{\left(P(x) - Q(x)\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x}$.

For each polynomial $P_n$, its "completeness" is measured by the smallest dissimilarity between itself and another $Q_{n-1}$ polynomial:

$c(P_n) = \displaystyle\min_{Q_{n-1}}{d(P_n, Q_{n-1})}$

How do I randomly draw parameters $a$ so as to ensure that

$c(P_n) \geqslant t$

?

---

Put it another way, the problem seems to be that the "average $P_n$" is the trivial, null, degenerated polynomial $P_n(x) = 0, \forall x \in [-1,1]^d$. Therefore, if I naively, randomly draw the parameters from $[-A,A]$, I'll get something closer from degenerated polynomials than to "complete" ones. How do I bias the sampling in $[-A,A]$ so as to avoid such almost-degenerated polynomials?

---

Bonus: if I could also relax the $A$ restriction but ensure that

$\forall x \in [-1,1]^d, P_n(x) \in [-1, 1]$

the satisfaction would be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [orthogonal polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalPolynomials.html), say [Legendre polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html).

Instead of writing
$$f_n=\sum_i^n \alpha_i x^i$$
with random $\alpha_i$, write
$$f_n=\sum_i^n \alpha_i P_i(x)$$
with $P_i$ the $i$th Legendre polynomial. Let $g$ be the best $(n-1)$th order approximation to $f_n$:
$$g=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left((2i+1)\int_{-1}^1 f_n(x') P_i(x') dx'\right) P_i(x)$$
$$g=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha_i P_i(x)$$
so the approximation error is given entirely by $\alpha_n$. Put a lower bound on $|\alpha_n|$, and you will have a non-degenerate polynomial.

Comment: This is really helpful! And thank you for these pointers :) The restriction to $[-1,1]$ codomain can be ensured if I enforce that $\sum{|\alpha_i|}=1$. Is the plain [product of Legendre polynomials](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/py_src/legendre_product_polynomial/legendre_product_polynomial.html) the correct generalization to multivariate functions? Is the class of functions you describe somehow restricted compared to the class of all polynoms that would fit? For instance, do I have any interest in generalizing to Jacobi polynoms instead?

Comment: Yes, the product is the generalization to multivariate functions. Any set of orthogonal polynomials up to order $n$ spans all polynomials up to order $n$, so there is no restriction. Using different types of orthogonal polynomials, which are orthogonal under different inner products, will also work, but the norm that you want to lower-bound (what you call dissimilarity) is the norm corresponding to the inner product for whatever set of orthogonal polynomials you use.

Comment: .. thus the awesomeness of Legendre polynomials. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: As an update on this: I can ensure that $f_n(x) \in [-1,1] \forall x \in [-1,1]^d$ by picking each $\alpha_i$ from a Dirichlet distribution, then I randomly flip their sign. The problem is that, the higher the degree $n$, the closer $f_n$ is from 0 (for the same reasons I suppose). How can I adjust the $\alpha_i$ so that the full range [-1,1] is exploited no matter the degree? I have tried with $tanh(a\times arctanh(f_n))$ transformations ($a\in\mathbb{R}^+$) with not much success. Maybe I should increase $a$ depending on $d$ and $n$.. Does this deserve another post?

Comment: You can always try the quick-and-dirty method of finding the maximum and minimum numerically and then rescaling the polynomial such that they are -1 and 1.

Comment: Arf, well, this does not work much because the edges remain wide.. and it is dirty indeed for the fn values do not depend directly depend on the parameters anymore ;P I'll hook up something with a $a$ parameters that increases with the degree instead ;)